# When running the downloadable CloudFoundry instance how do I retrieve the IP Address?

Tags: networking, cloud-foundry

I have downloaded the Micro Cloud Foundry v1.1.0 instance and am configuring it to work offline per the instructions available here:  http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/post/9962996319/working-offline-with-micro-cloud-foundry

However when I get ready to setup the SSH Tunnel (which I was successful with once before) I can't find the IP address anymore. According to the instructions it is supposed to be displayed where it shows "IP Address:  (network up)" but it no longer is displaying.

[image]

Any idea on another way for me to get the IP Address of the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try menu option 1, `refresh console` to see if it comes up? Or menu option 8, `restart network`?

You should be able to also login to the Ubuntu console and see networking information. Press `Alt-F2` to switch to a login prompt. For the username enter `vcap` and enter the password you gave when you first booted and configured the Micro Cloud Foundry VM. After you've logged in, run the command `ifconfig` to view network and IP information.

One last thing: confirm your VM NIC is set to NAT mode rather than Bridged. If you change it, be sure to reboot the VM for it to take effect.